# System of Differential Equations Question Assistance

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The following question has just left me confused with no real decent avenue of attack so any assistance on this would be appreciated.

For the system of equations

$t {\frac{d \vec x}{dt}} = A\vec x $

￼where A is an n×n matrix and $\vec x = [x_1,x_2,...,x_n]^T$. Assuming that $ \vec x = \vec wt^r$, where $ \vec w $ is a constant vector and r is a real number, show that $ \vec w $ and r must satisfy: $ (A − rI)\vec w $ = $\vec 0$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\vec{x} = \vec{w}t^r$ into the equation and subtract the LHS.

Comment: Hi,I think I can get down to 0=A * Wt^r - rWt^r but I stuck from here on in. I took t as a variable, derived the left side first after substituting, and then multiplied the vector on the left by the variable t.